# Como criar uma função que cria uma nova pagina no google sheets

Tags: javascript, script, google-sheets, google-app-engine

Como faço uma função que eu possa executar na planilha que gere uma página com o nome fornecido? Pois no exemplo abaixo estou recebendo o erro:
**Exception: You do not have permission to call insertSheet**

```
function criarPagina(nome) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.insertSheet(nome);
};
```

Comment: A seguinte função funciona, mas somente chamando a função no terminal.
`function criarPagina() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.insertSheet("Nome_daPg");
};`

Entretanto, eu quero a mesma tarefa, porém a chamando pela planilha.

Answer (score -1):

Tente isto:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Extras')
  .addItem('Criar planilha', 'showPrompt')
  .addToUi();
}


function showPrompt() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  const result = ui.prompt(
    'Criar Planilha',
    'Digite o nome da planilha',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  const button = result.getSelectedButton();
  const text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.insertSheet(text);
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {

    ui.alert('Por favor digite o nome para a planilha.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    ui.alert('Alerta fechado.');
  }
}
```

Isso vai criar um Menu "Extras" com um sub-menu "Criar planilha". Um alerta vai aparecer para digitar o nome da planilha.
Outra opcao seria adicionar um Desenho e associar um script a ele com o nome do script: **showPrompt**